# Delete table in Writer but preserve the contents

Tags: openoffice-writer

Is there a way to "explode" a table in OpenOffice.org Writer?

That is, delete the table, but preserve its contents in the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells and copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. Move outside the table and paste special, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, choosing the unformatted text option. Then delete the table.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+V doesn't seem to do anything on MS Office Word 2016

Answer (score 3):

Position the cursor in the table then go to `Table` > `Convert` > `Table to Text`.  This will prompt you to choose the separator for the cells.  This is the character that will be put between adjacent cells in a row. Adjacent rows will be separated by converting them into adjacent paragraphs.

This solution is easier and superior to copying and pasting as unformatted text, because converting table to text preserves formatting and any inserted images or other objects, like math formulas.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a whole document copy/paste-d from the web and you want to get rid of all the tables, but keep the content: Ctrl-A (select all), Ctrl-X (cut all, dont worry its just for a sec.), then Ctrl-Shift-V (special paste everything back), choose "unformatted text" and your document is table free.